# Checkbox with Accordion

Tags: angular, angular9, angular10

I am working on an angular app. I want to make an accordion with checkbox. Accordion can may or may not have children. If user selects parent then all children should be checked. If user selects children then that particular children only should get selected and parent checkbox should have "-".
Image is as follows:

[accordion_with_checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7SWi.png)

Almost all the examples I saw on internet doesnot have checkbox functionality with accordion. How can I do that?

Comment: Please show your data structure (in JSON)

Answer (score 0):

There's a solution using **Angular Material** [checkbox](https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/overview) and [expansionPanel](https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/overview).

It's a little bit complicated, but it's easy to understand, to reach your goal, you have to do this:

- clicking on a parent should affect all, so you need to call `setAll` method to apply the parent changes on all sub.
- `indeterminate` state or "-" mark, can be reached by a method `someComplete` that checks continuously that some of them are completed.
- clicking on a child should affect the parent, so you need to call `updateAllComplete` method.
- using `checkbox` in the `expansion-panel` will cause an issue, since clicking anywhere on the header will expand the panel, so we need to:

  - disable panel, to control it by yourself.
  - save and pass a value of expanded to `expansion-panel`.
  - add a `button` to expand it.

I made a solution for you, please check it here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5uhcys?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcheckbox-overview-example.html

Comment: accordion getting expanded on click of row and checkbox. Is there is any way to make it expand only on click of expand icon?

Comment: how can I catch data of checked ones in component and change color of inner rows if accordion is expanded?

Comment: Did you check the solution above?